# “need doing” vs. “need to do”

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, infinitives, gerunds, auxiliary-verbs

> I need a change. I need **going/to go** away for a while.

Would you please show me which one you use and why?

Answer (score 2):

### Standard usage

I would say:

> I need **to go** away for a while.

The situation with **need** is somewhat complicated. You *can* put a gerund after **need**, but it suggests that the subject of **need** will be the object of the gerund. For example:

> The house needs **painting**.

means the same as:

> The house needs **to be painted**.

Adding to the confusion, if the verb after **need** means the same thing actively and passively, then you can use either the gerund or the infinitive:

> The cows need **feeding** = The cows need **to be fed** = The cows need **to feed**.

because one sense of **to feed** means the same as **to eat**. This really isn't an exception, of course, so it doesn’t need memorizing. Or in other words, you don’t need to memorize it.

### In general

I don't think there is any general rule that tells which verbs should be followed by an infinitive and which verbs should be followed by a gerund. You just have to learn how each verb is used, one at a time.

[This question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive) has some more information.

### Unusual and nonstandard usage

You *could* say “I need going away for a while” to express strong emphasis. This wording is unusual, and suggests to a listener to hear “going away for a while” as if it were something done *to* you, like a medical treatment. This is tricky use of English, though, not something to start with, and not something you commonly hear. You should master the ordinary **need to** and **need *verb*ing** usages first. But this illustrates the way you can use the grammar to make a listener understand a phrase differently than usual, if the listener can find an interpretation that makes grammatical sense.

Whatever you do, don't read [this question about a nonstandard usage of **need**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5407/central-pennsylvanian-english-speakers-what-are-the-limitations-on-the-needs-w?lq=1) unless you want to sound like you’re from Pennsylvania or southern Scotland.

Comment: I agree that someone new to English has no need to learn the colloquial form. I also think that using that nonstandard construction with any arbitrary verb is probably pretty localized, but I've lived all over the eastern US and "needs doing" is relatively common. I think it is popular because it evokes the kind of folksy, individualist pragmatism that we like so much as a culture.