# "A question needs raising/to be raised" Which is preferable?

Tags: difference, infinitive-vs-gerund

I heard "a question needs raising" from a student of mine who is very fond of picking set phrases from manuals and it sounded weird to me. I would have used "A question needs **to be raised**"

I use the form "need + ing" when an  existing thing needs something done to it, like "the house needs cleaning". But I would never say "a new house needs building". If it's the creation of something that is needed I would use the passive infinitive: "a new house needs **to be built**"

Although a question can exist on people's minds before being asked, I still feel the raising of a question is more like the building of the house and wants the **to be asked** form.

I've found nothing about this in Swan's Practical English Usage, so I raise the questions to you:

Is there really a difference between the need + ing and the passive infinitive forms? Is "a question needs raising idiomatic"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“need doing” vs. “need to do”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43988/need-doing-vs-need-to-do)

Comment: Not really. I already knew that "my house needs cleaning" is equivalent to "...needs to be cleaned", as I said in my question. What I asked was if the ing form is possible when the thing that needs something done to it is not pre-existent to this doing, as in "a house needs building" or "the question that needs raising". Same goes for the rest of answers, thank you. But since no one mentions this difference I'll assume I was wrong and both forms are equally acceptable in these cases too

Comment: Whether or not "the thing that needs something done to it is not pre-existent to this doing" is irrelevant to the syntax here.

Answer (score 4):

In UK speech, 'concealed passive' statements like 'a question needs raising' are quite normal, if a little informal and conversational. They are often found in UK regional speech; I have a Yorkshire friend who does it a lot, e.g. 'my car needs [or wants] washing'. In *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland* (1865) by Lewis Carroll, the Mad Hatter says “Your hair wants cutting” to Alice.

Concealed passives are only found after three verbs, need, want, and require.

Comment: In some regional speech, it would even be "a question needs raised".

Comment: That's the [Central Pennsylvania dialect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/need-verb-ing-vs-need-to-be-verb-ed) usage typified by ***This car needs washed***. Which sounds terrible to most native Anglophones. But note [this comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/need-verb-ing-vs-need-to-be-verb-ed#comment4548_3515) pointing out that when the *subject* of that construction isn't the same as the *object* that needs to be [verbed], it's not quite the same. So there's no real problem with *You need your head examined* (but *Your head needs examined* is equally awful! :)

Comment: I'd be interested to know whether Central Pennsylvanians find *That question needs asked* or *Your head needs examined* acceptable. I suspect they only use the non-standard syntax in certain well-established contexts like the car needing [to be] washed.

Comment: I disagree that many Americans would see it as a mistake. We also use that idiom though perhaps not as frequently.

Comment: Especially things like: That question needs answering. These issues need resolving. Perfectly good American English.

Comment: @Lambie: I don't think anyone is suggesting there's a problem with *That question needs **answering***. My comment was directed at Especially Lime and whoever upvoted the comment implying we should accept *That question needs **answered***, which I suggest even Central Pennsylvanians might balk at.